# Jupyter notebook in blank when initiating a notebook - remote desktop

Tags: python, dll, jupyter, remote-desktop

I'm trying to run jupyter notebook on a remote desktop, which is highly secured (i.e. I had to activate scripting on internet explorer to be able to log in into outlook).
I am really new to this remote desktop thing and I would like to know why is this happening and if it has a solution. As a finance student, I really struggle with this stuff.
I used miniconda to run this. Also, this is shown in the terminal before opening the jupyter notebook window:
"[W 09:21:35.153 NotebookApp] Terminals not available (error was DLL load failed while importing winpty: The specified procedure could not be found.)"

[What is shown when I open a notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFSFr.jpg)

Best regards,

Comment: Literally having the exact same issue. Did you find a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure Internet Explorer supports jupyter notebooks, try with another browser if you can.